# Is it possible to find out how many (if any) places hold a reference to a ref type object?

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection

Lets say I have something like this

```
Dim A As String = "hi there"
Dim B As String = A
Dim Pile As New List(Of String)
Pile.Add(A)
```

Now the variable A, B and Pile(0) hold the same value but i want to make it so that if both A and B have changed to something else then the string also gets deleted from the Pile list.

I figured vb must have some idea on how many references to the same piece of heap are still in active code because it would automatically free the memory when the count reaches 0. Can I get that information though?

Comment: No; you can't do that.  .Net uses garbage collection, not reference counting.

Comment: What you're suggesting is a dodgy workaround for poor programming.  You should write proper code that will remove the item from the list when the variables change rather than trying to use low-level features like reference counting.  How hard can it be to set those variables via methods or properties and thus monitor them yourself?

Comment: Well in my specific situation, the Pile list is shared list of unique strings. Then i have a bunch of other lists that all check, Add or retrieve(if already present) their content against the Pile list. If I wanted to do what you're suggesting i would have to keep an extra list of lists to account for all the items that could still be holding a reference to something in the Pile list. Its more trouble then its worth(both performance and memory wise) so for now i just clean the Pile every time the program loads up but I figured a quicker cleanup would be a nice addition.. if its efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and .net doesn't do ref counting, so it doesn't know either.  It uses mark and sweep, which means that things that can be reached are kept and things that can't be reached are dropped.

It sounds like what you want in your list is a weak reference, which you could use to clean up your list periodically.  That is the closest that .Net comes to knowing if it's referenced or not that is exposed to the programmer.